# Autodesk Forge Design Automation API and Vault

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to figure out the best workflow to generate a PDF from a file in the Vault. I first tried referencing the URL in the address bar when logged into the Thin Client, didn't work.

Is this best workflow to accomplish this:

1. Download the file from Vault
2. Upload to cloud storage
3. Process the file in cloud storage with Forge API
4. Download resulting PDF
5. Check PDF in to Vault
6. Delete file from cloud storage

Answer (score 0):

Before going with Forge (which is supported via [Design Automation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/)), I would suggest you reviewing Vault built-in feature to generate PDF, see the following links:

[Publishing and Manage PDF Files](http://blogs.autodesk.com/vault/2017/12/publishing-and-manage-pdf-files/)

[New Automated PDF Creation for Document Control](http://help.autodesk.com/view/VAULT/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-C52856B5-DB38-4202-AAB4-D75AEB975AFB#GUID-C52856B5-DB38-4202-AAB4-D75AEB975AFB__SECTION_A5C2899DA88C4959883F9A4DE2ED9AB4)

Comment: Hi Augusto,

I am aware of these added features, but we are not utilizing the design release process and our DWGs are in 3d.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Vault APIs for checking in and out of Vault as well as performing Gets. We currently do not have Vault to Forge APIs, but you can use today the Forge APIs. You will need to build a custom application to perform the communications and file transfer between the two locations.